# Set Python GCC compiler

Tags: python, gcc

I'm currently using Python 3.5.2 from Anaconda, and would like to change the gcc compiler used from v4.4.7 (the default) to the one I have installed (v6.2.0). I can't find how to do this anywhere. Any tips?

Comment: why do you need different compiler ? Are you going to compile Python from source code ? Then download source code and use own compiler to compile Python.

Comment: This is due to an error attempting to run Theano, which encounters a massive interpreting error when attempting to run any sort of test.

Comment: maybe you should ask question with this errors.